# Report fields overlapping

Tags: kiwi-tcms

Is there any way to change the formatting of a test run report, or is this a bug?

When I run the report I get overlap between the "tested by" and "category fields:
['tested by' overlaps 'category'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxZPp.png)

Comment: please providing a minimal reproducible example (mind: not your full code, but a small example written for the sole purpose of demonstrating your problem :)

Comment: This is an issue with the GUI.  So basically the steps are:
1. Perform a test run
2. Click "report" at the top of the test run.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bug with how information is formatted on this screen. Feel free to report as a GitHub Issue if you haven't already.

For the record: nicely formatted TR reports are part of our backlog related to telemetry feature - https://kiwitcms.org/blog/kiwi-tcms-team/2019/03/03/legacy-reports-become-telemetry/

The entire test run page UI, and the report itself will be redesigned and such issues shouldn't happen